# Inheritance Pattern

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am finding my naming conventions rather bothersome. I seem to be re-using the child specific names too much. In my Example below, I have a Widget which has-a Connection which has-a Config. Each of these objects has specialized classes for Foo and Bar types.

So my FooWidget has-a Foo-Connection which has-a Foo-Config. The same for Bar. In C++ I've ended up with nine different header files.

- widget.h
- connection.h
- config.h
- foo_widget.h
- foo_connection.h
- foo_config.h
- bar_widget.h
- bar_connection.h
- bar_config.h

I cant help but look at this a feel like it isn't right. My instincts tell me something needs to be changed. It's like there is a design pattern somewhere to be taken advantage of. But I can't find a better solution.

So I guess my question is the following: **Is there a design pattern that will improve this design?**

[image]

--  I am having difficulty wording my question correctly. Please excuse me, I will update as the question itself becomes more clear.

Comment: Out of most common patterns, it looks most like 'Bridge' as you seem to try to separate an object’s interface from its implementation. Link: http://www.dofactory.com/net/bridge-design-pattern.
I don't know if it will improve the design, but at least it may show that your pattern is more common than you may think.

Unless your concern is with the creation of the objects, then you should also look into Abstract Factory.

Comment: It's not possible to give you advice, just seeing the structure. We need some information about the roles of these classes and what they are supposed to do and how they should interact. If this should be a MVC like pattern, I can't see anything wrong with it from this perspective.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's nothing **wrong** with doing things that way. Many like to put one class per header, in general. If you don't like looking at so many headers you might organize them by directory, or project tree filter, etc.

This is all a question of style. As long as functionality is untouched, the best option is a function of that *funny feeling* you have, and same for the folks supporting your code down the road. Maybe this answer can make that funny feeling go down for you, or maybe not.

Second, this very much depends on the use of each class. If the `Foo` and `Bar` classes are small, they can be put in the header that contains the encapsulating class. Perhaps add a forward declaration for the sake of the parent class, and finish declaring it at the bottom of the header. Bonus points if they're all related (for example `FooConnection` is a subclass of `Foo`) because this shortens declaration space.

If they're relatively small classes, there may be no harm in declaring the `Foo` and `Bar` classes within the definition their base class. Then there is no `FooConnection`--it's actually a `Connection::FooConnection`. In this case `Connection` doesn't just define the base for `FooConnection`, it **owns its very definition**. That means every time you use a `FooConnection` in your code, you are thinking in the context of a `Connection`. I **rarely** do this myself, primarily because I don't like typing `Connection::` all the time, but also because there are so few cases where I only use a class in one context.

If the encapsulated classes are `protected` or `private`, then they're only used by the parent class itself (and `friend` classes and maybe subclasses, what have you). Then, since limited context is established, and if the class declarations are small (<50 or <100 lines), you can declare `FooConnection` and `BarConnection` within `Connection` and still maintain readability.

Bonus point: if you do end up declaring classes inside classes, you might take advantage of namespace separation. I don't know the uses of these classes, but I'm guessing `FooConnection` isn't a connection itself, but a `Foo` that belongs to a `Collection`. So then you might declare a `Foo` and a `Bar` class for each of `Widget`, `Connection`, and `Config`.

Comment: If OPs diagram follows the normal convention of a [UML class diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) then `Foo` and `Bar` **inherit** from `Widget`. `Widget` does not "encapsulate" `Foo` and `Bar`. And `FooConnection` is a `Connection`. Inheritance is the very definition of "is-a".

Comment: Edited to clarify my wording. In that paragraph I was thinking of a specific example where a base class does encapsulate (or *yield*) subclass instances. My wording seemed to limit the discussion of that subclass's definition to that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the structure of your classes but without seeing what these classes do it is going to be hard to give advice on how to improve your design.

I think it is good style to have one header file per class. It makes things easier to find and you can easily use directories (or filters in your IDE) to organise your files. For example you may find it easier to structure your files:

```
|--Foo
   |--foo_widget.h
   |--foo_connection.h
   |--foo_config.h
|--Bar
   |--bar_widget.h
   |--bar_connnection.h
   |--bar_config.h
|--widget.h
|--connection.h
|--config.h
```